# Time out before it can be clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game the user clicks on the letters to spell the word. When a letter is clicked on it animates into the correct area.

The problem is when you click them to fast the animation  messes up and the letters overlap.

To solve this I want to add a timeout of 1 or 2 seconds before a clickable can be clicked again.

**How would I do this, and where in my code would I put it?**

Here is the code for the clickables

```
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
var targetPos = target.position();
var currentPos = $(this).offset();
var b = $(this);

if (target.length) {
    target.addClass("occupied");
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        if (!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length) {
            var wordIsCorrect = 0;
            $('.drop-box.spellword').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("data-letter") == $(this).find("div").attr("data-letter")) {
                    wordIsCorrect++;
                }
            });
            console.log(wordIsCorrect);
            console.log($('.drop-box.spellword').length);
            if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Well Done!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass("wordglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Try Again');
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled');
                $(wrong).show();
                audioF.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(right).hide();
                //$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.drop-box.spellword').animate({
                    'opacity': 1
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('occupied').html('')
                });
            }


        }
    });

}
```

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var animation = false;
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
  if(animation) return;
  animation = true;
```

and add to your callback:

```
animation = false;
```

**Full liting:**

```
var animation = false;

$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if(animation) return;
animation = true;
setTimeout(function(){animation = false;},1000); // Can't click letters for 1 sec

var target = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
var targetPos = target.position();
var currentPos = $(this).offset();
var b = $(this);

if (target.length) {
    target.addClass("occupied");
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        if (!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length) {
            var wordIsCorrect = 0;
            $('.drop-box.spellword').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("data-letter") == $(this).find("div").attr("data-letter")) {
                    wordIsCorrect++;
                }
            });
            console.log(wordIsCorrect);
            console.log($('.drop-box.spellword').length);
            if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Well Done!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass("wordglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Try Again');
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled');
                $(wrong).show();
                audioF.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(right).hide();
                //$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.drop-box.spellword').animate({
                    'opacity': 1
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('occupied').html('')
                });
            }


        }
    }, function(){
      animation = false;
    });

}
```

There I used setTimeout instead of callback.

Comment: I put full listing to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't let the user click the letters at all now. Here is a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/cTGGA/4/ @Arthur Halma

Comment: I updated my answer. Please use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: Thanks but this one doesn't work. Could you have another look? Also the old one only works for the first word @Arthur Halma

Comment: strange, it works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/taran2l/cTGGA/13/ (test with 3sec delay pass on all words)